# Report design needs solving crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to generate a report that generates results as follows:

If there are results of YES and NO for Picture Exist against a common Pattern Number as shown in Image Number 1, I would like the results to be generated.

If there are results with only YES for Picture Exist against a common pattern number, I would like the results to not be generated.

Id there are results with only NO for Picture Exists against a common pattern number, I would like the results to not be generated.

Pattern number is TOOL_Tools.Tooling_Number
Picture Exists is Max of @Picture Exist, this is a formula field as shown in Image Number 2.

---

Image Number 1

[image]

---

Image Number 2

[image]

---

Image Number 3

This is how the tables are linked.
[image]

---

If you need any more information please ask

Comment: you need all these to be done in a single report?

Comment: An example might be a good idea.

Comment: Edited my post to give an example

Comment: Still no clear the question. The image posted is what you need or what you have?

Comment: The attached image is just a cut from a report than generates all of the products from my system. I would like a report that generates results which has YES and NO in picture exists against the same pattern number.

I don't know how to go about this, that it why I am seeking help.

Comment: Maybe a suggestion of how I would go about doing it, I would try and use the suggestions as a base point to try and solve it myself, but I am unsure of what kind of restraints there are in crystal reports.

@Hariharan Anzbazhagan, yes i would like to do this in a single report.

Comment: put it in a simple way, get us some fields from your database and try to explain using that ! as said by @EmanueleGreco still your question is not clear...

Comment: @Hariharan Anbazhagan - I have restructured the question, hopefully this is enough, if now please ask what else you would need